# Installing CFEngine on Ubuntu 12.04 - Can't stat file

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04, cfengine

I am trying to install CFEngine on Ubuntu 12.04.  For simplicity's sake, I am using a virtual machine with a fresh (with updates installed) version of Ubutu Server.  I installed CFEngine 3.5.1 from the CFEngine repos.  However, I keep getting the error:

```
error: Can't stat file '/var/cfengine/inputs/lib/3.5/paths.cf' for parsing. (stat: No such file or directory)
```

Sure enough, the file doesn't exist.  In fact, there is no /var/cfengine/inputs/lib folder.

Any ideas what I might need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 3.5.1, please see https://cfengine.com/dev/issues/3137

The workaround for now is to check out the code from https://github.com/cfengine/core, and copy core/masterfiles/lib/ to /var/cfengine/masterfiles/lib/ on your machine. Then things should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First things first :D
Did you bootstrap your host?
If you are testing single instance of cfengine you have to set up policy server which is a policy distribution server and a client at the same time.

To set up policyserver you need to bootstrap it to itself:

```
/var/cfengine/bin/cf-agent -B <your IP>
```

Policy files are located in /var/cfengine/masterfiles/
When cfengine executes, he does a copy of this folder to all it's clients also the local one to /var/cfengine/inputs/.

Policy that does that is in update.cf file so for manual enforcing you would run this:
/var/cfengine/bin/cf-agent -IKf update.cf (but if you wait a few minutes cfengine will do that automatically at the next scheduled run preformed by cf-execd)

for more info have a look on documentation site:
http://cfengine.com/docs/3.5/getting-started-installation.html

Comment: Yes, I did boot strap it.  The boot strapping reported that it was successful, but it complained about not finding paths.cf as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by commenting out all references to the "lib" (not the library folder) folder in promises.cf.  It's not ideal since I am not sure what I am all disabling, but it fixed my problem and it seems that cfEngine is working as it should.